# Can SSH via putty but fail via terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, cygwin, putty

I've been trying to access my raspberry server using ssh. In Windows 7 I'm using cygwin. Here the command I used.

```
ssh pi@10.34.8.56 -v
```

And here the result

```
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Connecting to 10.34.8.56 [10.34.8.56] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/Maswari/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Maswari/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Maswari/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Maswari/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Maswari/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Maswari/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Maswari/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Maswari/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 10.34.8.56:22 as 'pi'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection reset by 10.34.8.56 port 22
```

I also try to ssh via Ubuntu inside vagrant using this command

```
ssh pi@10.34.8.56 -v
```

And the result was

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.34.8.56 [10.34.8.56] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by 10.34.8.56
```

But somehow, when I try to connect using PuTTY, everything is fine. I can access my server. I look up ssh log and give me particular result

```
sshd[6553]: fatal: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth]
sshd[6823]: fatal: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth]
sshd[6934]: Accepted password for pi from 172.19.0.5 port 51395 ssh2
sshd[6934]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
```

SSH from Cygwin and terminal seems produce this error

```
sshd[6553]: fatal: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth]
```

I've already reinstall ssh in the server, regenerate the keys, but still give the same result. Does anyone know how to solve this. So I can access my server through terminal or PuTTY.

Answer (score 0):

> sshd[6553]: fatal: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
>   [preauth]

This means that there is a ssh-key generated and only the person with that key can access it. To fix this do...

```
sudo apt-get purge openssh-server
```

then

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

last

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

then try

```
ssh -i deployment_key.txt demo@192.237.248.66
```